# Application failed 2 times due to AM Container: exited with exitCode: 1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I ran a mapreduce job on hadoop-2.7.0 but mapreduce job can't be started and I faced with this bellow error:

```
Job job_1491779488590_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1491779488590_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1491779488590_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://erfan:8088/cluster/app/application_1491779488590_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1491779488590_0002_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
17/04/10 13:40:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

What is the reason of this error and how can I solve this problem?

any help appreciated.

Comment: Your application master for your job is failing to start. Try checking the yarn logs for a more detailed message. `yarn logs -applicationId APP_ID`

Comment: Thanks, I wrote this command but I confront with this message what is it mean? Usage:yarn [options]   yarn: error:  no such option: -a

Comment: Please add the command you attempted to run to your question

Comment: Hi I got this error when trying to start a Glue job from StepFunction, do you know what's the issue?

Answer (score 9):

Check logs on Resource Manager:

```html
namenodeip:8088
```

you got this error:
[image]

Now open terminal and check actual problem:

```html
yarn logs -applicationId <APP_ID>
```

Example: APP_ID = application_1535002188113_0001

In mine case it show permission issues:

so i gave it:

```html
   sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 775 /user/history
   
   or
   
   sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/history
```

Answer (score 6):

You can see the application logs for the actual issue.

For this you can open the namenode web interface on 
`namenode_ip:50070`
Here you can see browse option, click it.
In the submenu, select logs.
Now select the userlogs.

Here you can see the list of applications you ran.

Open the link `application_1491779488590_0002` for your above mentioned job inside you can see the logs for each map & reduce task. 
Open map/reduce job log link.

Inside it you can see:  sys, error, stdout files.
From these log files you can get the actual error and can fix it.

Or you see these logs in 
`$HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs/application_id`  path.

Application failed 2 times because if application master failed for
some reason, by default it will try to execute the application one
more time. The AM retry property can be set to 1 to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the yarn-site.xml file and add this code(ps: %HADOOP_HOME%: is your environement variable) :

```
 <property>
       <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
       <value>
            %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\lib\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\*,
            %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*
       </value>
    </property>
```

- it worked for me :)