# Unable to start hive using tez execution engine

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

Im using Hadoop 2.7.3 version and hive 1.2.1 version.
I face problem with hive using tez engine. Is there any setup error or other kind of error ??

> Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>
> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in  [jar:file:/home/hduser/tez/tez/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in  [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an  explanation.
>
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning: TezSession has already shutdown.
>
> Application application_1568628322588_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1568628322588_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://rohan-VirtualBox:8088/cluster/app/application_1568628322588_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
>
> Diagnostics: Exception from
>   container-launch.
>
> Container id: container_1568628322588_0002_02_000001
>   Exit code: 1
>
> Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely similar to [Application failed 2 times due to AM Container: exited with exitCode: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425678/application-failed-2-times-due-to-am-container-exited-with-exitcode-1).

Essentially the code you pasted does not contain the actual error code - so we cannot help much with it. You need to find the exact error message, by going to your Resource Manager and looking at the logs there.